# How broadcast variables are used in dask parallelization

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have some code applying a map function on a dask bag. I need a lookup dictionary to apply that function and it doesn't work with client.scatter.

I don't know if I am doing the right things, because the workers starts, but they don't do anything. I have tried different configuration looking to different examples, but I can't get it to work. Any support will be appreciated.

I know from Spark, you define a broadcast variable and you access the content by variable.value inside the function you want to apply. I don't see the same with dask.

```py
# Function to map
def transform_contacts_add_to_historic_sin(data,historic_dict):
    raw_buffer = ''
    line = json.loads(data)

    if line['timestamp] > historic_dict['timestamp]:
        raw_buffer = raw_buffer + line['vid']

    return raw_buffer

# main program
# historic_dict is a dictionary previously filled, which is the lookup variable for map function
# file_records will be a list of json.dump getting from a S3 file

from distributed import Client
client = Client()
historic_dict_scattered = client.scatter(historic_dict, broadcast=True)

file_records = []
raw_data = s3_procedure.read_raw_file(... S3 file.......)
data = TextIOWrapper(raw_data)
for line in data:
   file_records.append(line)

bag_chunk = db.from_sequence(file_records, npartitions=16)
bag_transform = bag_chunk.map(lambda x: transform_contacts_add_to_historic(x), args=[historic_dict_scattered])
bag_transform.compute()
```

Answer (score 4):

If your dictionary is small you can just include it directly

```
def func(partition, d):
    return ...

my_dict = {...}

b = b.map(func, d=my_dict)
```

If it's large then you might want to wrap it up in Dask delayed first

```
my_dict = dask.delayed(my_dict)

b = b.map(func, d=my_dict)
```

If it's very large then yes, you might want to scatter it first (though I would avoid this if things work out with either of the approaches above).

```
[my_dict] = client.scatter([my_dict])

b = b.map(func, d=my_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My dict is quite large (600000 keys). What I don't understand is: if I use dask.delayed or client.scatter I don't need to compute the dict? I mean, if I use b.compute makes the computation of the dict?